# Problem finding click event on UItab bar button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to iPhone development and I'm facing a problem where I can't find the click event of the Tab Bar button in iPhone.  Can anyone tell me how to find it?

Comment: Looking at the comments to my answer, it looks like your app crashes at second click then I sueggest you to post your code and modify the question because it's not clear that it crashes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the Delegate to your `UIViewController` like this,

`@interface MyRootViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate> {`

and then in the `@implementation` make sure you have the following...

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myViewController1, myViewController12, myViewController4, myViewController5, nil];
```

Good Luck! :)

Comment: i found click event first time when i click onbar button but at second time the program crashes.

Comment: I think the target you set is not reachable. Did you Back Trace?

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot change the delegate of the UITabBarController's UITabBar. Program will crash if you do this, with the following message: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed."

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tabbar controller's delegate method

`- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't fire when reselecting the same tab. I'm looking for a way to discover that.

Answer (score 0):

To listen for `UITabBar` item selection, you need to set your `UIViewController` as `delegate` of the `UITabBar` then implement this method of the `UITabBarDelegate`

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

Comment: i have already added this Deleaget function but it is not working.

Comment: have you set your current view controller as delegate? Something like like `tabBar.delegate = self;`

Comment: i found click event first time when i click onbar button but at second time the program crashes

Comment: ah ok that's another problem btw... you should write it in your question because it's not clear. It looks like you just can't reach the click event...

Comment: NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 UIViewController *vc;
 self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:0];
 vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
 vc.title = @"Local";
 [listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
 self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
 
 [vc release];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers
          animated:YES];

Comment: The delegates method are              - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar*)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
 NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
  [self activateTab:item.tag];
 [item setEnabled:FALSE];
 }

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbc didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
 
 if( viewController.navigationController == tbc.moreNavigationController ){
  NSLog(@"pop to more list");
  [tbc.moreNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 }
}

Comment: not here :-) Post the code inside your question (by editing it) to let other people to help you...